# What is an ODBK file and how to restore that?

Tags: odbc, progress-database

I have recently come across a situation where I am required to restore an ODBK file. Basically this is a database file of Intergy Server (An EHR platform). I don't know how to restore that file into a supported DB engine and how can I view the data. Upon searching I came to know that this is an OpenEdge DB file.
The server is running a Postgres engine as well but there is no table related to that EHR.

Comment: Postgres or Progress? The 2 are very different fish.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you please tell me if I want to restore an ODBK considering its a Postgres database file how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

ODBK isn't any abbreviation officially used by OpenEdge. But if it indeed is a backup file from Progress OpenEdge you need to use `prorest`:

```
prorest newdatabase backedupfile
```

Start by reading this [article](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P18487)

Comment: Thanks for answering, my intent is to extract the data out of Progress DB, How is that possible any tutorial or help would be appreciated alot.

Comment: If its the most recent version (not likely) you can download and install a free development environment. If its older you better contact Progress Software and discuss it with them.